# Run MakeTable queries in external accdb

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have about 20 "MakeTable" queries locally that work just fine if I call it like this:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qry325_NMC_Final")
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

I have moved them to another accdb to keep the front end clean. I'd prefer not to link the tables so that I don't see this clutter, because it will continue to grow about 6 fold by the time I finish.  It's ok for 20 MakeTable queries and their tables to be in separate accdb's.

How do I update the code to work the same but run the 'MakeTable' queries from different accdb's?

Answer (score 1):

To run a query in another database you might try something like this:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("FullPathAndFileNameOfDb")
db.Execute "qry325_NMC_Final", dbFailOnError
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: How do I get past the prompting / error 'tbl325_NMC_Final already exists?  Apparently, 'DoCmd.SetWarning false' doesn't work when used with either db.execute - or (calling queries in external databases?)

Comment: You might execute `db.Execute "DROP TABLE tbl325_NMC_Final"` to delete the table right before executing the query?